# Nuget package not installing dependencies for .NETCoreApp

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

I've created a nuget package which has 2 assemblies. One targeting .Net Framework 4.0 and another targeting .Net Standard 1.6.

This seems to work without any problems. However, the version targeting .NET Standard requires a couple of extra dependencies to function so I added these as dependencies in the nuspec file and rebuilt.

The dependencies show up as expected in the NuGet Package Manager but when I reference the package from a .Net Core or .Net Standard Application, it does not add references for the dependencies.
The package seems to install fine, with no errors in the log.

This is the relevant part of my nuspec file:

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework="netstandard1.3">
        <dependency id="System.Collections.Specialized" version="4.0.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" version="4.3.0.0" />
    </group>
    <group targetFramework="netcoreapp1.0">
        <dependency id="System.Collections.Specialized" version="4.0.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" version="4.3.0.0" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

A little more info:

I tried removing the grouping from the config above and just had the dependencies listed with no grouping, then I tried installing the package on a regular ASP.NET project.

When you install the package via Package Manager, a window pops up listing the packages that are being installed and in this case, it lists my package plus the dependencies. All good.

However, when I install the same package on a .NETCoreApp or .NETStandard project, only my package appears in the list.

**Edit 2:**

I've been discussing this with the very helpful people at NuGet support and discovered that if we use the same package, added to a .NET Core app in Visual Studio 2017 then it works fine, it's only in VS 2015 that the problem occurs.

They've asked me to raise an issue on [github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5130).

Comment: The dependencies should be added transitively on restore, do they show up in the consuming application's obj/project.assets.json file? What exactly do you mean by "not added"?

Comment: When I say not added, I mean that the nuget package itself appears as a reference under 'References' in the solution explorer. I would expect the dependencies to appear there as well but they do not. Also, no, they don't show up in any json files.

Comment: So the answer is, the issue exists only in VS 2015. VS 2017 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In projects that use package reference to manage nuget dependencies, you do not have a project.json. Instead, all your references are available in a single place i.e. the project file.
In dotnet core, or projects that use [PackageReference](http://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html), reference to only the immidiate dependencies are listed. So, if you add a reference to package A, which in turn depends on package B, B would not show up in your project file. This is a one of the biggest advantages of PackageRef where we don't clutter the project file with gazillion dependencies which the consumer probably doesn't care about.
Install your nuget package to a project, navigate to the project_root/obj/project.assets.json and open this json, you'd see your package listed along with its dependencies. If you see your intended dependencies here, it validates that package is authored correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not quite that simple. When I try and use the functions of the assembly from the package, it will give me a 'The type 'x' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced' error, even though that assembly is listed as a dependency in the NuGet package. So there are definitely references missing.

Comment: I would really like to see a repro....can you share it here or send me an email at karann[at]microsoft[dot]com

Comment: Sure, the issue on github (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5130) has the problem NuGet package embedded at the bottom.

Comment: In vs2015, .NET Core, was in preview. As you found out, this works with VS2017. I would recommend using the minClientVersion property to ensure that the package is consumed only in 2017 as I don't foresee the fix coming to 2015 anytime soon.

Comment: You might be right. Thanks for the tip on minClientVersion.

Comment: Ah, further problem. minClientVersion allows me to specify a a minimum NuGet version but even if I install the latest NGPM beta build in 2015 (3.5.0.1996), the dependencies are still not added when I add the package. If I were to add a minClientVersion of e.g. 4.0 then I can't know if it will actually work when the VisualStudio 2015 NGPM plugin is updated to that version so not sure that's the answer. Also, I'd still want the package to install on 2015 for projects targeting .NET framework and minClientVersion would not allow that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it causes by cache? try:

Clean cache at `VS2017 > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)` (Actually in %USERPROFILE%\.nuget)

That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing `nuget.org` package source.

```
Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources
```

[image]